# Can't connect to Github private repo with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, ssh

I don't seem to be able to connect to a Github private repo with Eclipse.

I am able to connect to the repo through the command line on windows by using mysysgit with putty (Pageant), without the need to provide login/password. Is use this article and it works [LINKE](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx).

Eclipse does recognize my git repo, but when I right click and pull/push, nothing really happens: it's says it's pulling 0% in the eclipse status bar, but it doesn't change...

I have added the ssh private/pub key to the eclipse pref I followed the helpful links in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse), but not having a lot of luck.

When adding the github repo through the import and searching, I do get the error shown in the screenshot :
[image]

And when I add the private repo through the Eclipse import uri, I get also an error, see screenshot (using git protocol):
[image]

I also tried the https protocol, but then get the following error:
[image]

I tried many things as you can find these errors with Google, but didn't manage to solve it :(
I am using putty Pageant, and that works on the command line. But in the [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) I read that github doesn't work with Putty, but in my case it does :(...

Any idea how to solve this?

**EDITED:**
I just noticed that a pull request does work, but it take like 10 min to end, while it costs 10s on the command line. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ssh, you would need to configure Egit in order to show where your pubic/private keys are: [Eclipse SSH Configuration](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)

If you are using plink/pagent keys (instead of openssh ones), see "[Using putty's pagent with egit in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14723487/6309)".

Regarding https, many causes can prevent to access a remote repo: [anti-virus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194291/6309), [JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855097/6309), certificates issue, ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The ssh stuff I know and it's configured. I added the plink.cmd, good tip, thanks. Https: I stopped the firewall and antifvirus stuff, but had no effect. I will digg some more.

Comment: @edbras double check your ssh config with http://www.ringabell.org/en/utiliser-git-avec-une-authentification-par-clef-privee-sous-windows-avec-putty/: make sure `GIT_SSH` references your `plink.exe`.